# Return list of Vertex (list-2), whose relationship are only with a subset of another vertexes(list-1)

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

My question is that I want to return all the vertexes whose relations are only with a subset of another list of vertexes.

For example I will pass a list of person, for ex: Ram, David and Alan. I should return back the person list who are only friend to Ram, David or Alan (in any combination, any of them, with any two or all of them)

How can I do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a sample graph but you are essentially going to be doing something like `g.V().has('person','name',within('Ram','David','Alan')).out('friends_with').values('name').dedup().toList()`

Comment: Thank Kelvin, In case a person's friend list has values ('Ram', 'David, 'Alan', 'Tim'), Will your query return this guy. My use case is, it should NOT as this guy is friend with one more person 'Tim' which is not part of the input list.

Comment: Ah OK - not quite. It just finds all people who are friends with them. So will need to be tweaked a bit to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so from the comments/discussion - I think this is what you are looking for:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').
   filter(not(out('knows').has('name',without('Ram','David','Alan')))).
   out('knows').
   path().by('name')
```

Cheers,
Kelvin